# Regex for removing whitespace

Tags: python, regex, function

```
def remove_whitespaces(value):
    "Remove all whitespaces"
    p = re.compile(r'\s+')
    return p.sub(' ', value)
```

The above code strips tags but doesn't remove "all" whitespaces from the value.

Thanks

Comment: this getting more and more ridiculous. do you even understand what does this code do?

Comment: And whats so ridiculous about it? Asking several questions in a couple of hour? Thats "ridiculous"?

Comment: your question quite clearly indicates that it's not the case!

Comment: ridiculous is asking *why do you I still have spaces there?* when you're replacing your pattern with the them!

Comment: What are the "tags" you refer to? HTML tags? Don't use regex to parse HTML.

Comment: @Mark: there was another function there (you could see it in another question) that was deleted.

Comment: Well, its a simple function which takes in a value, strips whitespace (regex) and returns it. Yes, I'm an *absolute beginner* yes, but I think I'm learning quite fast and I hope you're not seeing any repeating questions? I understand they seem like stupid questions to you pros but I *have to* ask if I don't understand, thats what SO is for I believe. Several questions in a day, maybe that annoys you but I'm practicing Python today (Sunday) in my free time, won't get time every day. :)

Comment: @SilentGhost it was deleted because I figured it out myself. See, I don't want to waste anyone's time. I just ask what I don't understand and its NOT ridiculous to ask, is it?

Comment: Nimbuz, I don't really know what all the hubbub is about, but it's generally bad form to delete your question when you figure it out. SO isn't just for people to get answers to questions they ask, it's also for people to be able to find their question already asked and answered. The best solution is to post the answer, as you came to understand it.

Comment: @Nimbuz: SO is for asking educated questions. You should try to debug your code, or read documentation before coming here. Come here afterwards if you still do not understand how to solve your problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The fastest general approach eschews REs in favor of string's fast, powerful [`.translate`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=translate#str.translate) method:

```
import string
identity = string.maketrans('', '')

def remove_whitespace(value):
  return value.translate(identity, string.whitespace)
```

In 2.6, it's even simpler, just

```
  return value.translate(None, string.whitespace)
```

Note that this applies to "plain" Python 2.* strings, i.e., bytestrings -- Unicode's strings' `.translate` method is somewhat different -- it takes a single argument which must be a mapping of `ord` values for Unicode characters to Unicode strings, or `None` for deletion. I.e., taking advantage of `dict`'s handy [`.fromkeys`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=fromkeys#dict.fromkeys) classmethod:

```
nospace = dict.fromkeys(ord(c) for c in string.whitespace)

def unicode_remove_whitespace(value):
  return value.translate(nospace)
```

to remove exactly the same set of characters.  Of course, Unicode also has more characters you could consider whitespace and want to remove -- so you'd probably want to build a mapping `unicode_nospace` based on information from module [unicodedata](http://docs.python.org/library/unicodedata.html?highlight=unicodedata), rather than using this simpler approach based on module [string](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html?highlight=string#module-string).

Answer (score 3):

```
p.sub(' ', value)
```

should be

```
p.sub('', value)
```

The former replaces all whitespace with a single space, the latter replaces with nothing.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe <strike>value.join(p.split())</strike> ''.join(value.split()) could work for you?

Comment: I think you mean `''.join(value.split())`

Answer (score 1):

`re.sub('\s*', '', value)` should also work!

Answer (score 0):

`re.sub(r'\s', '', value)` function works well for me, in this case.

Answer (score 0):

@OP, compile your regex pattern outside, so you don't have to call re.compile everytime you use the procedure. Also you are substituting back to one space, that is not removing spaces is it?

```
p = re.compile(r'\s+')
def remove_whitespaces(p,value):
    "Remove all whitespaces"    
    return p.sub('', value)
```

lastly, another method not using regex is to just split on whitespaces and joining them up again

```
def remove_whitespaces(value):
    "Remove all whitespaces"    
    return ''.join(value.split())
```